# Default route that can proxy to existing routes

Tags: playframework, routes

Say I have routes like:

```
GET   /blog/:blogName          controllers.blog.show(blogName: String)
GET   /blog/:blogName/:postId  controllers.blog.getPost(blogName: String, postId: Int)
```

So this would work fine for URLS like:

```
www.example.com/blog/corporate
www.example.com/blog/corporate/1231
```

The goal is to use the standard routing but I want to somehow support the following.
Say I want a custom url for the blog with name 'corporate' to work at this URL:

```
   corporate.example.com
   corporate.example.com/12321
```

Since actions are just functions, I was hoping I could somehow create a "catch-all" route that would then simply proxy the request to an existing route like.

Example, the URL:    `corporate.example.com/12321`  I would want to do:

```
def catchAll(): Action = {

   val blogName = request...  // extract the subdomain "corporate"
   val postId = // ... extract postId from the URL

   controller.blog.getPost(blogName, postId)
}
```

Note:  I may have 100's of blogs like this, so I can't hard code this into the routes.  The idea is I want to know if I can somehow re-use the existing routes by "proxying" requests that don't match a route to the correct route after I filter out the parts from the URL myself manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps define routes like this:

```
# These two routes can do the "proxying"
GET    /                controllers.blog.view
GET    /:postId         controllers.blog.catchAll(postId: Int)

# These can be your fallback routes
GET   /blog/:blogName           controllers.blog.show(blogName: String)
GET   /blog/:blogName/:postId   controllers.blog.getPost(blogName: String, postId: Int)
```

Then in the blog controller your "proxy" functions:

```
def view = Action.async { request =>
     // request.host = "subdomain.example.com" in your example, though it may be wiser to try a more sophisticated function with  a regex to handle the extraction.
    val subdomain: String = request.host.split('.').head
    show(subdomain)(request)
}

def catchAll(postId: Int) = Action.async { request =>
    val subdomain: String = request.host.split('.').head
    getPost(subdomain, postId)(request)
}
```

Since the controller functions `show` and `getPost` returns an `Action`, which when applied is a function `Request => Future[Result]` , we just pass along the original request to `Action.apply`.

Note that since `Action.apply` returns a `Future`, I needed to change `view` and `catchAll` to use `Action.async` to handle the `Future[Result]`.